# Entityform admin interface broken

Tags: entities

Im using the 2.0 version of Entityform. I have 236 fields. When I rearrange the fields in Manage Display and click save nothing happens. When I click a gear to edit a frameset it says "please wait" then nothing happens.

Thoughts?

EDIT: I wanted to mention that I'm not getting any PHP errors.

Comment: It's possible you're going over the max input variables, have you checked your php error log?

Comment: Im not sure where to check that. Im using the Acquia dev desktop V2rc. @thumbson

Comment: It's in php.ini @MichaelRizzo (wherever your current server solution keeps that file), look for [`max_input_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars). Depending on your setup you may be able to override in the vhost or .htaccess

Comment: I uncommented `max_input_vars` and then restarted apache. It was set to 1000. No luck. @clive

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are getting any php errors?